# cygwin emacs-w32 failed to start after update to 28.1

Tags: emacs, cygwin, emacsw32

desired fingerprint: 1339d21bbf6849dc9ba04d950e4618b83aad01478e7cdeae44b7d3fa904f7f9e
found fingerprint: c6ccf821f95573982bb6b4111eb5ec918c13d929570be3e9af132afb6e35a979
emacs: could not load dump file "/usr/bin/emacs-w32.pdmp": not built for this Emacs executable

Comment: not a programming question

Comment: the file seems to exist only on version 27. https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=emacs-w32.pdmp&arch=x86_64 . Try to reinstall `emacs-w32` package

Comment: reinstall 27.2 solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I removed /usr/bin/emacs-w32.pdmp and it seems to be working now.